# Dynamically added RecyclerView entry not auto resizing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while now and cannot get this to work. I have a RecyclerView which has a child added to it upon a button press (this is a test case at the moment). As you will see in the code below, When onBindView is called, the text is changed. However as the title says, the text does not auto resize to fill the box in question.

How would I be able to do this?

RecyclerViewEntry.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                               android:id="@+id/ma_rv_ple_layout_root"
                                          android:background="@drawable/background_border_rc"
                                               android:padding="15dp"
                                               android:clickable="true" 
                                               android:focusable="true"
                                               android:layout_margin="5dp"
>
<TextView
        android:text="@string/ma_rv_ple_project_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:id="@+id/am_rv_ple_project_title_label"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        android:breakStrategy="balanced"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:maxLines="1"
/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ProjectListAdapter.java

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjectListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // TODO: Create and build our ViewHolder.
    String entry = ProjectManager.getInstance().getProjectItem(position).getProjectName();

    holder.getProjectNameTextView().setText(entry);
}
```

Comment: Autosizing textview is not recommended when using `wrap_content` layout height (which it is in your case). Additionally textview will only autosize down, so you might find your text being too small when you scroll and viewholders are recycled.

Comment: So would it be more beneficial to use a programmatic way around it by using use cases such as when box is say 150dp big it's this x size and then when box is 300dp it's y size?

Comment: Either set the ConstraintLayout height in xml with a number such as 150dp or 200dp or whatever you want. or matchparent. Or, as you say programatically in java/kotlin setting layoutparam to different heights